# Creating a custom URL for reverse local proxy with NGINX

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, mac, nginx-reverse-proxy, url-routing

I'm trying to set a custom URL for a reverse proxy. From what I understand, the code should be fairly straight forward. Here's what I've got:

```
worker_processes 1;

events {

     worker_connections 1024;

}

http {
    server {

        listen 8080;
        server_name www.example.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
        }
    }
}
```

Afterwards in terminal I made sure to type in the command:

```
sudo nginx -s reload
```

When I go to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) I get "This site can’t be reached", but when I type "localhost:8080" into the url it successfully loads the content from localhost:3000.

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: does the custom url can be resolved? please show `nginx -Tt`

Comment: running that command I get: nginx: the configuration file /Users/user/homebrew/etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /Users/user/homebrew/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Comment: but nginx -T exposure the full configuration which should be added to the question

Comment: I deleted everything else so what you see in the question is the full configuration.. is this where I went wrong? lol I was following a tutorial for a simple reverse local proxy, found here https://kirillplatonov.com/posts/simple-reverse-proxy-on-mac-with-nginx/

Comment: I already asked if the current custom url can be resolved? and will it be resolved correctly?

Comment: Forgive me I only started learning Nginx yesterday. You are asking if I enter the command nginx -T if it is resolved correctly? I get the same response as I mentioned before: "Syntax is okay" and "test is successful" and then it just prints out everything I have in my configuration file, which is exactly what I have posted in the question above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136903/discussion-between-jmsapps-and-djdomi).

Answer (score 0):

need to locate SSL_certificate

server {
server_name example.com

listen 443 ssl;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/koko.ztidev.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot